# Is it possible to measure the spin of an electron without moving it?

Tags: experimental-physics, electrons, momentum, quantum-spin, experimental-technology

I know that the position and spin operators commute, so it is theoretically possible. What I want to know is, what experiments currently exist that achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to physics stack exchange, make your question more descriptive and also show  your thoughts and efforts what you have thought or done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of insufficient prior research effort. Information about spin resonance experiments is sufficiently available.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of its spin the electron has a [magnetic dipole moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment). That means if we place it in a magnetic field the two states aligned with and against the magnetic field have different energies. The magnitude of the energy difference depends on the strength of the field and the size of the magnetic dipole moment, which in turn depends on the spin. So by measuring the interaction of the electron with a magnetic field we can measure its spin

There are various ways to measure this energy difference, and hence the spin, without moving the electron. The most widely used is probably [electron paramagnetic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance).

Comment: I've heard of this, but how exactly is the energy measured. Any experiment I've seen still results in adding momentum to the electron in some way

Comment: @ISB: did you look at the link I provided to the Wikipedia article on electron paramagnetic resonance. That gives a good description of the process. The process just rotates the magnetic dipole. No momentum change occurs.

Comment: I did, and the process involves photon absorption, as well as many cases resulting in changes in orbital angular momentum. Both of these tell me that overall momentum is not undisturbed

Comment: @ISB: In EPR there is no change in orbital angular momentum. There is obviously a change in the spin angular momentum because the direction is flipped. The angular momentum changes by $\pm 1$ when a photon is absorbed or emitted. However there is no, or at least no significant, change in linear momentum.

Comment: I would think that if the angular momentum changes, then the electron must exhibit non-identical linear momentum behavior. EPR was always explained to me as a thought experiment or assumed the use of stern-gerlach devices, which change the linear momentum